# Call Go function from VBA via DLL

Tags: windows, go, dll

I'm brand new to Go and am not experienced in compilation issues or with C++. So starting from zero, I'm trying to compile a dll in Go and call a function in VBA. I'm developing the Go in Linux, and switching computers to try it in Windows. The VBA part may not be essential. It does serve as a way for me to test the dll call.

Here's the simple Go code:

```
  package main

  import (
      "C"
      "fmt"
  )

  func main() {
      var x int
      x = Test()
      fmt.Println(x)
  }

  func Test() int {
      return 666
  }
```

It works for `go build`, `go install`, and calling `main` from the console.

I compile with these two commands, which both run without error, in this order. Should I be running both of them? (I'm way out of my depth here.) The target system is Windows 10, 64 bit with Office 365 ProPlus (but is Excel fundamentally 32 bit?):

`env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o hello.dll hello.go`

`env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -buildmode=c-shared -o hello.dll hello.go`

I copy the file, `hello.dll`, to `System32` and in VBA I declare:

`Public Declare Function Test Lib "C:\Windows\System32\hello.dll" () as Long`

I get the error of Run-time error '53': File Not Found, which I understand may be caused by a missing dependency.

So I run Dependency Walker. This shows me a top level of HELLO.DLL and 4 levels under it of KERNEL32.DLL, MSVCRT.DLL, WINMM.DLL, WS2_32.DLL. And it gives:

```
Error: At least  one required implicit or forwarded depende3ncy was not found. 
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresovled import due to a missing export function in a a delay-load dependent module.
```

There's a huge number of yellow question marks. And dozens of Modules with Error opening file, with names like `API-MS-WIN-CORE-...` and `EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-...` as well as `HVSIFILETRUST.DLL` and `IESHIMS.DLL` and `EMCLIENT.DLL`

So I've got a few moving parts in my lap and I'm way out of my depth. I'm hoping I'm just missing a simple step (maybe put the dll in a different folder??). If this should be an ambitious or difficult task, I should probably let it go.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't call an exported function from a Go executable from VBA. VBA has its own COM-friendly threading model, but the Go runtime has its own, conflicting, ideas about how threads should work. I don't know what guarantees Go makes about C-style exports from a Go program, but I think the best way to interop with a Go program from VBA is to run it as a separate process and communicate via stdin/stdout or system-provided pipes using a standard serialization format (e.g. JSON).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I couldn't remember where dlls I've had declared in VBA in the past were put. (I thought that this way might better find the dependencies... .) The relevance of VBA is flexible for me. I make tools for personal or desk use in VBA. I was thinking about trying to utilize concurrency via a dll in VBA (since it's single-threaded). But ultimately I did mean my functions to be deployed on an enterprise level. I'm on the modeling side. Managers (non-technical) are pushing me towards R or python. I wanted a compiled proof of concept.

Comment: I should say that the ultimate enterprise environment is centered on Oracle and Oracle R. (And there's potential support for Python with IT reluctant about it.) I don't know how infrastructure works at that level (I work at the algorithm level, not the system level). My notion was just to translate my VBA model (monte carlo) into a compiled form, and that Go looked a lot less daunting to take up than C++. And then argue later about how to deploy it. And avoid R and Python.

Comment: The system will load a module referenced by file-name (rather than file-path) by checking every directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable of the host process - by default on Windows this includes `C:\Windows\System32` - but it is very, very bad practice to place files in that directory just to ensure modules can be loaded by file-name alone.

Comment: The system will load a module referenced by file-name (rather than file-path) by checking every directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable of the host process - by default on Windows this includes `C:\Windows\System32` - but it is very, very bad practice to place files in that directory just to ensure modules can be loaded by file-name alone.